# Freemarker call Java Filter

Tags: freemarker

In my Java code im adding a POJO

```java
rootMap.put("_Field_",field);
```

there is a function "getFilteredHtml" that for the time being does nothing but return the string
that is given as a parameter (the idea is later to alter this - but for test purposes it keeps the html untouched).

```java
/**
 * get filtered html for this field
 * @param html
 * @return
 */
public String getFilteredHtml(String html) {
    return html;
}
```

in the Freemarker template I am using this function like this:

```
${_Field_.getFilteredHtml(fieldRef?eval!"-")}
```

which creates the following error message:

```
Root Cause: freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Argument type mismatch;
can not unwrap argument #1 (class: freemarker.ext.beans.NumberModel, toString: "4") 
to class java.lang.String
```

I tried to understand what http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html
wants to tell me but this is all greek to me. How can I avoid this Beanwrapper behaviour and make
sure the function getFilteredHtml is simply called with all this mumbo jumbo about wrapping and unwrapping?

Comment: looks like modifying getFilteredHtml to public Object getFilteredHtml(Object html) does the trick. The error message is simply misleading because it talks about freemarker.ext.beans.NumberModel when trying to say that a string is not expected when the input is a long (or some other numeric type)

Comment: If you were using FreeMarker 2.3.20 (which is 1 years old now), the error message would be: "Argument type mismatch; can't convert (unwrap) argument #1 value of type number+extended_hash (Integer wrapped into f.e.b.NumberModel) to String."

Comment: @ddekany - thanks I've upgraded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no other answer showed up I'm citing my comment:

looks like modifying getFilteredHtml to public Object getFilteredHtml(Object html) does the trick. The error message is simply misleading because it talks about freemarker.ext.beans.NumberModel when trying to say that a string is not expected when the input is a long (or some other numeric type)